# How to scale a UIView from left to right and back?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scaling

I want to have an UIView to appear by scaling from left to right if I hit a button. If I hit the button again, the view should scale away from right to left.

I found an explanation how to do it for left to right, but even this solution is working only once. If I hide the view and play the animation again it scales it from the centre again.
Also scaling it back from right to left doesn't work either as it disappears immdiatly without any animation.

Here's my code so far:

```
if(!addQuestionaryView.isHidden)
    {
        //Reset input if view is hidden
        addQuestionaryInput.text = ""
        self.addQuestionaryView.isHidden = false
        let frame = addQuestionaryView.frame;
        let rect = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
        addQuestionaryView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:1,y: 0.5)
        addQuestionaryView.layer.position = leftCenter
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                       animations: {
                        self.addQuestionaryView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 1)
        },
                       completion: { _ in
                        self.addQuestionaryView.isHidden = true
        })
    }
    else
    {
        self.addQuestionaryView.isHidden = false
        let frame = addQuestionaryView.frame;
        let rect = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        let leftCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        addQuestionaryView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y: 0.5);
        addQuestionaryView.layer.position = leftCenter
        addQuestionaryView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                       animations: {
                        self.addQuestionaryView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        },
                       completion: nil)
    }
```

As said the appearing part works once and then starts from the centre again. The disappearing part doesn't work at all.

Comment: Do you want it to actually scale (squish the view) — or do you just want it to appear from the left and then disappear to the right?

Comment: No the plan was to scale it so it has a little look like Android reveal animations. 
Not simply moving it from left to right and back. It should look like it opens not sliding in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "to scale it so it has a little look like Android reveal animations" means (and I hope I never do; I've never seen an Android phone, I never hope to see one).

But do you mean something like this? This is done by animating a *mask* in front of the view, thus revealing and then hiding it:

[image]

Here's the code used in that example:

```
class MyMask : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let r = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height)
        UIColor.black.setFill()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.fill(r)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lab: UILabel!
    var labMaskOrigin = CGPoint.zero

    var didAddMask = false
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if didAddMask {return}
        didAddMask = true
        let mask = MyMask()
        mask.isOpaque = false
        let w = self.lab.bounds.width
        let h = self.lab.bounds.height
        mask.frame = CGRect(x: -w, y: 0, width: w*2, height: h)
        self.lab.mask = mask
        self.labMaskOrigin = mask.frame.origin
    }

    var labVisible = false
    func toggleLabVisibility() {
        labVisible = !labVisible
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
            self.lab.mask!.frame.origin = self.labVisible ?
                .zero : self.labMaskOrigin
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. Thank you perhaps that gives me the right direction what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
    addQuestionaryView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y: 0.5);
    addQuestionaryView.layer.position = leftCenter
    addQuestionaryView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 1)
```

Then in your animate with duration block use the code below instead of `CGAfflineTransform`

```
addQuestionaryView.frame = CGRect(0,0,500,100)
```

Replace 500 width whatever width you want it to be.

Ans to close it back up do this:

```
addQuestionaryView.frame = CGRect(0,0,0,100);
```

Comment: But will this not just move the view instead of scaling?

Comment: Sorry i read your question wrong, let me know if that works and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I also tried your solution. I think it would generally work, for my needs matts solution works better as it already takes care of the subviews. (I didn't mention that subviews should be animated together, sorry). With this approach I would have to animate the subviews separately.
Also somehow the back animation didn't work. It waited until the time passed and then called the completion block, but the animation was never shown. But that's most likely related to my project. Thank you anyway!